# Getting transparent window

Tags: gimp, transparency

I open my photo, i right click colors, I try to choose alpha to color but is it not highlighted and nothing happens. Could someone send me suggestions on how to fix, oh yeah I am a dummie at this. Please make it easy.

Thank you
Loriblackdog

Answer (score 1):

Color to alpha replaces a specific color with transparency, so it's not terribly useful on a photo (except in a few occasions but likely unknown to "a dummy at this").

Color-to-alpha is not selectable when the target is not a RGB color object, off the top of my head this can happen in three cases:

- The image itself image isn't a RGB image (title bar says "Grayscale" or "Indexed color"). Use `Image>Mode>RGB` to make it a RGB image.
- You selected a channel by mistake (often by `Select>Save to channel`). Open the Layers list (Ctrl-L) and select a layer by clicking on it
- You are working on a "Layer mask" (possibly by accident). The status line at the bottom of the image window says " Mask": uncheck `Layer>Mask>Edit layer mask` (or use `Layer>Mask>Delete layer mask` if you created it by mistake)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did what you said in the first bullet image>mode>RGB. I appreciate your spelling it out. I am sure I will have many more questions :)

Comment: Mark the answer accepted and earn two kharma points:)